# $\mathrm{Ann}(I \cap J) = \mathrm{Ann}(I) +\mathrm{Ann}(J)$ if $R$ is self-injective

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, ideals, injective-module

> If $R$ is injective as an $R$-module, then for every two ideals $I$ and $J$ we will have $\mathrm{Ann}(I \cap J) = \mathrm{Ann}(I) + \mathrm{Ann}(J)$.

I made an effort for an hour but it was not helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annihilator of an ideal $I$ in a module $M$ is just $\mathrm{Hom}_R(R/I, M)$. Now use the inclusion $R/I\cap J\to R/I\oplus R/J$ and injectivity of $M$.

Comment: sorry, please explain more about last part . Last statement is not clear for me.@Mohan

Comment: I saw some error in your answer . 1.there is equality between them in my question not isomorphism . 2. I think R/I  and R/J are not independent.@mohan

Comment: $\mathrm{Ann} I=\mathrm{Hom}_R(R/I,M)\subset M=\mathrm{Hom}_R(R,M)$. So, we get a natural map, by homing with $M$, the map I wrote in the answer, $\mathrm{Ann} I\oplus\mathrm{Ann} J\to \mathrm{Ann} I\cap J$, which is onto by injectivity of $M$, all considered as submodules of $M$.